# What is the importance of setting `IList` capacity?

Tags: c#, .net, list

What is the importance of setting a lists capacity at creation?

For example, say I *know* for sure that my list will only contain *n* items throughout its lifetime.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inside of a `List<T>`, there is a statically sized collection that holds your items. Once you reach the capacity of that collection, the `List<T>` re-sizing it which is a performance hit (may or may not be significant to you).

By setting the initial capacity, you are avoiding having to perform those re-sizing operations.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever a list needs to exceed its current capacity, reallocations of memory and moving around of stuff must happen, which takes time and effort.

If you know ahead of time exactly how large the list will be, you can avoid this.

Answer (score 3):

You'll make a little speed because the list won't have to be grown. Growing a list is O(n) where n is the current number of elements, and the standard `List<>` grows by doubling its current size. Everything considered, adding an element to the end of a list is still on average an O(1) operation (this because in the end to insert n elements you'll have on average n inserts to the end (each one an O(1) operation) and n copy operations between old buffer and newer buffer (each one an O(1) operation), so each add is on overage O(1))

Answer (score 3):

This will improve performance slightly, as the necessary memory will be allocated when you create the List, and the CLR won't have to increase the List size when you add more elements.

Note that even if you specify a List size, it will be increased anyway if you add more elements than expected.